# Spark LuceneRDD for JSON data

Tags: apache-spark, lucene

Can we use LuceneRDD to Index JSON data.I tried to Index JSON format data using LuceneRDD, but it doesn't show correct result

Code:

```
read.filter($"influencer" === "markpantoni").show(truncate = false)
    val luceneRDD = LuceneRDD(read)
    val influencerName = "markpantoni"
    val result= luceneRDD.termQuery("influencer", "markpantoni",1)
    result.take(1).foreach(println)
```

read dataframe scheme:

```
root
 |-- influencer: string (nullable = true)
 |-- matches: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- influencer: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- totalNumberOfOverlaps: string (nullable = true)
```

Result:

```
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|influencer |matches                                                                                                                                                     |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|markpantoni|[[chefsymon,4], [TheSchott,3], [RyanJohansen19,2], [builtincbus,1], [AAAOhio,1], [RMHCofCentralOH,1], [NASA,1], [CityScene,1], [daytonpulse,1], [wexarts,1]]|
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

[score: 5.685845/docId: 1/doc: Text fields:influencer:[markpantoni]]
[score: 5.685845/docId: 1/doc: Text fields:influencer:[markpantoni]]
```

Comment: You should be in the habit of showing your code. In this case there is a missing class. Are you sure this package is in lucene-core and not in lucene-codecs? Dig into your dependencies and make sure transitive dependencies are being followed and found. Dig into your maven caches and see if the artifacts are present.

Comment: Added lucene-codecs - 7.1.0 library to pom file and getting error "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.lucene.codecs.DocValuesFormat: method <init>()V not found"

Comment: I'm guessing lucene-codes 7.1.0 is not compatible with 6.6.0 of the other libraries, and there is a missing constructor signature from the POV of those other classes.

Comment: Edited question above. Code and updated dependency added.

Comment: It looks like this library has been refactored a few times. The stack trace will tell you what is referencing the missing default constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your response, able to overcome error related to dependencies.